# Assinging text and value to select in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two **td**. In each td is a **select** with n **options**. I want to assign different text and a value to each first option from select.

this is what i tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var c = 1;
        $("td select").each(function(){
            if (c == 1){
                console.log(this);
                $(this + " option:nth-child(1)").val("-1");
                $(this + " option:nth-child(1)").text("Choose role");
            }else if(c == 2){
                $(this + " option:nth-child(1)").val("-1");
                $(this + " option:nth-child(1)").text("Choose status");
            }
            c++;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't do anything. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
 $(this).find("option:nth-child(1)")
```

instead of

```
 $(this + " option:nth-child(1)")
```